# JReport doesn't print String with parenthesis

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm printing a receipt however, when I tried to put parenthesis on my string it doesn't print on the receipt..

```
engine.CoreSet.DrawText("THIS INVOICE/RECEIPT SHALL BE VALID FOR FIVE\"(5)\"YEARS FROM THE DATE OF THE PERMIT TO USE.".ToString(), x + 95, y1 + y2, 50, 75, System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center);
```

I have tried escaping the `(5)` but still doesn't work... I'm new to `JREPORT` and I don't know why it doesn't print when there's a `()` parenthesis on my string.... I also tried omitting the parenthesis and it worked fine...
but what I want is to include the parenthesis.

I am using `C#` and `Visual Studio` as my IDE.

thanks in advance..